# Can I use Present tense for actions that have just happened?

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

Could someone help me with this please...
 I wanted to know if I could use the present tense to describe something happened just a few seconds ago instead of using past tense?

For example:

> (A) Where is Rhian?
>
> (B) She goes to the market. (She went to the supermarket)?
>                     can I still use Present Tense in this case?

Comment: The present tense is fine here, but not in the way you wrote it (as an answer to the question). Rather than *she goes to the market* it would be much more natural to say *she is going to the market*. (If she just left, then she's still on her way—the activity of "going" is still in progress.)

Comment: "Where is Rhian?" is not in the past tense. "She goes to the market." is not the same as "She went to the market."

Comment: See [ell.se] Good Luck.

Comment: The so-called present tense is, for most verbs, not used for the present or the recent past, but in a habitual sense, or for future intentions. As Jason says, you could use the form that is actually used for present actions - the so-called present continuous - if you want to mean that she is still on the way. Otherwise you need to use some sort of past form - either a simple past, or a perfect.

Comment: The only possible grammatical answers to your question:  She went or She has gone to the market. She goes is out. I wonder what your native language is.....

Comment: You can also omit the verb entirely, and just say "She's *at* the supermarket"

Answer (score 1):

Here's a weird thing: in English (at least UK English which is where I'm from!) you **don't** use the **present tense** much to refer to something that's currently happening.

> She goes to the market. (1)

Instead you use the **present participle**:

> She's going to the market. (2)

The difference is that (2) means now, at this moment, she is going to the market. (1) you would use if she generally has a habit of going to the market, for example

> She goes to the market *every Wednesday*.

In your particular case, personally I would vote for the past tense because the event of her leaving is in the past:

> She's *just* gone to the market.

*(italics mean the word is optional)*